# How to write the output of a function into a table cell

Tags: macros, libreoffice-calc

I am using a macro in LibreOffice Calc sheet that gives date using function "=NOW()+14" into a cell. How can I permanently write the output of the function to the cell so it does not generate new date every time I open the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the cell.  Edit->Paste Special; make sure the "Text" box is SELECTED and the "Formulas" box is NOT.  Hit OK.  You may need to format the cell as "date" or "time" (otherwise it shows time as a decimal fraction of 24 hours and date as days since December 31, 1899).

Although if you're already using a macro, why don't you calculate the time in the macro and put the time into the cell instead of a formula?

```
Dim CalcTime : CalcTime = Now + 14
oCell.setString(CalcTime)
```

Comment: When I try to run this macro, I get 
    `BASIC runtime error.
    Object variable not set.`

Comment: This isn't an entire macro, it's a code snippet.  Of course you have to assign the variable `oCell` prior to this snippet, for example `oCell = ThisComponent.getSheets(0).getCellByPosition(0,0)` will assign it to cell A1 on the first sheet of the workbook.